# How to use variables that have been declared in another class in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I have two classes of which one extends **Activity** and the other extends **BroadcastReceiver**.I have declared a few variables in **MainActivity** class and need to use this in the **IncomingSms** class. How do I use the variables. Here is my code.

From the MainActivity class I need to use the variable full_address in my IncomingSms class.
**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
              if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                     StrictMode.ThreadPolicy stricMode = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                                  .permitAll().build();
                     StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(stricMode);
              }
              TextView address_textview =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.address);
              address_textview.setText(getAddress());
       }
       public String getAddress() {
       String address1 = "";
       String  address2 = "";
       String  city = "";
       String state = "";
       String country = "";
       String county = "";
       String  PIN = "";
        String full_address = "";
        try {

            JSONObject jsonObj = getJSONfromURL("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" +"12.9818619" + ","
                    + "77.6480391" + "&sensor=true");
            String Status = jsonObj.getString("status");
            if (Status.equalsIgnoreCase("OK")) {
                JSONArray Results = jsonObj.getJSONArray("results");
                JSONObject zero = Results.getJSONObject(0);
                JSONArray address_components = zero.getJSONArray("address_components");

                for (int i = 0; i < address_components.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject zero2 = address_components.getJSONObject(i);
                    String long_name = zero2.getString("long_name");
                    JSONArray mtypes = zero2.getJSONArray("types");
                    String Type = mtypes.getString(0);

                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(long_name) == false || !long_name.equals(null) || long_name.length() > 0 || long_name != "") {
                        if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("street_number")) {
                            address1 = long_name + " ";
                        } else if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("route")) {
                            address1 = address1 + long_name;
                        } else if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("sublocality")) {
                            address2 = long_name;
                        } else if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("locality")) {
                            // Address2 = Address2 + long_name + ", ";
                            city = long_name;
                        } else if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("administrative_area_level_2")) {
                            county = long_name;
                        } else if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("administrative_area_level_1")) {
                            state = long_name;
                        } else if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("country")) {
                            country = long_name;
                        } else if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("postal_code")) {
                            PIN = long_name;
                        }

                    }

                    full_address = address1 +","+address2+","+city+","+state+","+country+","+PIN;
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
              return full_address;

    }
        public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url) {

               // initialize
               InputStream is = null;
               String result = "";
               JSONObject jObject = null;

               // http post
               try {
                   HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                   HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                   HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                   HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                   is = entity.getContent();

               } catch (Exception e) {
                   Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
               }

               // convert response to string
               try {
                   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                   String line = null;
                   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                       sb.append(line + "\n");
                   }
                   is.close();
                   result = sb.toString();
               } catch (Exception e) {
                   Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
               }

               // try parse the string to a JSON object
               try {
                   jObject = new JSONObject(result);
               } catch (JSONException e) {
                   Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
               }

               return jObject;
           }

}
```

I need to use lat1 and lng1 variables in MainActivity.

**IncomingSms.java**

```
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // Get the object of SmsManager
    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        try {

            if (bundle != null) {

                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                    String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                    String body = currentMessage.getMessageBody().toString();


                    Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: "+ senderNum + "; message: " + body);

                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "senderNum: "+ senderNum + ", message: " + body, duration);
                    toast.show();

                    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(body, ",");
                    Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(context, "tokenizer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast1.show();
                    int numberOfTokens = tokenizer.countTokens();
                    String[] splitArr = new String[numberOfTokens];

                        splitArr[0] = tokenizer.nextToken();
                        splitArr[1] = tokenizer.nextToken();

                        Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(context, "split", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast2.show();
                         Toast toast3 = Toast.makeText(context, splitArr[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast3.show();
                             Toast toast4 = Toast.makeText(context, splitArr[1], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                toast4.show();
                    String lat=splitArr[0];
                    String lng=splitArr[1];
                    double lat1=Double.valueOf(lat);
                    double lng1=Double.valueOf(lng);





}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a separate class

```
 public class Constants {

 static long lat1,long1;

  public static long getLat1() {
    return lat1;
   }

   public static void setLat1(long lat1) {
    Constants.lat1 = lat1;
   }

   public static long getLong1() {
       return long1;
    }

   public static void setLong1(long long1) {
    Constants.long1 = long1;
    }

  }
```

from your  Broadcast set this value like Constants.setLat1(lat1), and in your activity get values using Constants.getLong1()

Comment: If the variables are as public then why do you need getter/setter methods ?

Comment: @Kedarnath you have a point. so either make variable public or create getter/setter method for variable

Comment: For best practice, always make private variable, and make public method to access private variable. Now in this case , OP needs to make private static variable in one class and public getter() method in same class. While in next class OP can access by className.getter() method :)

Comment: i have update my code. check it now, hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Well, I do not have any problem. OP has the problem. :), besides your code is not perfect. Instead of `Constants.lat1 = lat1;` , it should be `this.lat1 = lat1;`

Comment: well my 'your' indicate to OP :).but @Kedarnath thax for correcting me.

Answer (score 0):

Create one new class called **Constant.java**

```
public class Const {
    public static int A = 0;
    public static String selectedImagePath;
}
```

and then in your classes use it like

```
public class A extends Activity
{

....
....

Const.A = //whatever;
Const.selectedImagePath = //whatever.;
}

public class B extends Broadcastreceiver
{
 Const.A = //whatever;
 Const.selectedImagePath = //whatever.;

}
```

then same you can try in your broadcastreceiver class also.

Comment: I could do that but unfortunately one of my classes extends Broadcastreceiver. So how can i use it here?

Comment: Then you can do one thing create one new class Like Constant.java and declare your variable over there and access it.

Comment: @user3384417, Check my edited answer. and let me know still if you have any problem.

Comment: i did as you said but the variable has to be final to be used in the logic hence i am not able to view it in another class.what can i do?

Comment: Create separate java file and declare this variable inside this, if you do so it will not ask for final.

Comment: this is the error i get in BroadcastNewSms although i declared it in a dummy class called dummy.java. and was manipulated in IncomingSms as you have advised.    **lat1 cannot be resolved or is not a field**

Comment: @user3384417, can you post your code. for dummy.java and other where you have used the variable of dummy.java

Comment: this is in dummy.java                             'public class dummy {
 public static double la1 = 0;
  

}'
 this is my IncomingSms.java                                     'double lat1=dummy.la1;
         lat1=Double.valueOf(lat);   '                                                this is broadcastnewsms                   '  double asdf=IncomingSms.lat1;  '

Comment: I am not getting what actually you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

use the `Intent` (you need one to start the other `Activity`) or a `Bundle` to pass data through Activities.